# Why yml files inside microservice are not able to read values from yml files of core?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have `core` like this:

```
application-dev.yml

app:
  region: east


application-uat.uml

app:
  region: south
```

Then I have a microservice with following yml files

```
application-dev.yml

direct:
  url:  http://test-${app.region}.com


application-uat.yml

direct:
  url:  http://test-${app.region}.com
```

I believe, my spring application should be able to read values from core but it's not reading values from core. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by core? It’s a  module of the microservices? An external jar?

Comment: @Pp88 It's a separate folder just like we have microservices folders inside a project.

Comment: How are you linking the properties files to the classpath? Aren’t you using maven or gradle?

Comment: @Pp88 Yes, I am using maven

Answer (score 0):

You have to change one of the two file name and the micorservice module must depend on core module. Then you can add in `application-dev.yml or application-uat.yml` of the microservice module

```
spring:
  config:
    import: classpath:core-dev.yml
```